# Is there a way I can resolve this error of "could not find confusionMatrix"?

Tags: r

I installed caret `install.packages("caret")`and tried to compute the confusionMatrix of my KNN classifier and the error message I got was

```
  > confusionMatrix(table(fit_KNN192 ,testMarker))
  Error in confusionMatrix(table(fit_KNN192, testMarker)) : 
  could not find function "confusionMatrix"
```

I installed the caret package again and the Library yet the same error still surfaced.

```
  package ‘caret’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

  The downloaded binary packages are in
  C:\Users\Unene\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8qWy14\downloaded_packages
  > library(caret)
```

I again run LDA classifier  and everything went well but when it was time for me to compute my confusionMatrix the same error came up. Please is there anything I am not doing right?

```
 > confusionMatrix(table(fit_LDA_predict$class, LDAtesting$marker))
 Error in confusionMatrix(table(fit_LDA_predict$class, LDAtesting$marker)) : 
 could not find function "confusionMatrix"
```

Comment: Does `caret::confusionMatrix(table(fit_LDA_predict$class, LDAtesting$marker))` work?

Comment: > caret::confusionMatrix(table(fit_LDA_predict$class, LDAtesting$marker))
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.4 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.6 is required

Comment: I decided to update my RStudio packages and though it still gave me the same error, I used your method and it worked both for the LDA and KNN. Thanks Allan